# load images in ascending order by id

Tags: jquery, html, css, json

I am reading Images by json . i have total 16 images .. i want to read images by Ascending order like . id1,id2,id3 and so on .

Currently they are loading in descending order

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var globe;
    /*   Reading the data from XML file*/

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "photos.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('item').each(function() {
                var path = $(this).attr('path');
                var width = $(this).attr('width');
                var height = $(this).attr('height');
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                var alt = $(this).attr('alt');
                var longdesc = $(this).find('longdesc').text();
                var description = $(this).find('desc').text();
                $('#myImageFlow').prepend('<img src="' + path + '" id=' + id + '  height="' + height + '"  width="' + width + '" longdesc="' + longdesc + '" alt="' + alt + '"/>');
                imgArr[i] = description;
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: just a note: it is `xml` and not `json` (you load with `ajax` and not with `json`. `json` is a format like `xml`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `.append()` instead of `.prepend()`

try this

```
$('#myImageFlow').append('<img src="'+path+'" id='+id+'  height="'+height+'"  width="'+ width+'" longdesc="'+longdesc+'" alt="'+alt+'"/>');
                    imgArr[i] = description;
```